# Sophisticated PDF presentation on a secondary display

Tags: macos, pdf, presentations, beamer

I am using MacTeX (LaTeX or XeTeX, depending on the task) with Beamer class to generate my presentations which are hence in a PDF format. I would like to run presentations just as in Apple Keynote – that is fullscreen, in native resolution of the secondary screen (e.g. a projector) and the same, but not in fullscreen, accompanied by notes, the picture of the next frame and possibly a timer plus handy features such as darkening of the secondary screen (everyone probably know the way Keynote does it).

One very good known solution is called [SplitShow](http://code.google.com/p/splitshow/), but the development seems to be terminated since December 2010 until they find a new project owner and the current state of the application does not provide everything mentioned hereinbefore. It has been over a year so I am not hoping for introducing new features by the current owners. One major flaw is in my opinion the inability to enter fullscreen mode separately for each display, which means that I can not bring a video player over the fullscreen presentation on the secondary display (which is possible with Adobe Acrobat Pro).

I am quite surprised that this is the only solution that I have found. Acrobat Pro is a disappointment, considering its price. Does anyone know an alternative or perhaps want to continue in the development of SplitShow (which is overall great)?

How do you run your PDF presentations on a Mac?

Comment: hmm, LibreOffice has extension called Presenter Console which does exactly what you need. I tried it on linux and as I know, there is also LibreOffice for Mac. But it uses OpenDocument format for presentation and not PDF...

Comment: @Juhele PDF is essential. Otherwise I would just use Keynote with LaTeXiT to typeset equations.